# Git blaming a merge conflict with deleted lines

Tags: git

When merging I sometimes see these empty entries with merge conflicts. I believe these occur because there were lines that were deleted at the same position where new lines were added. How can i find which commit deleted those lines?

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
import           Util.Random                        (toPercentage, toPercentageIO)
>>>>>>> origin/mybranch
```

Using git blame I can see what commits added the new line but how can i tell who deleted the empty lines in git blame?

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Main.hs (Not Committed Yet 2020-05-11 18:44:03 -0700  53) <<<<<<< HEAD
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Main.hs (Not Committed Yet 2020-05-11 18:44:03 -0700  54) =======
882df874c1d4e1be600128b5893c9d745d5fc36d Main.hs (user              2020-05-11 18:10:05 -0400  55) import           Util.Random                        (toPercentage, toPercentageIO)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Main.hs (Not Committed Yet 2020-05-11 18:44:03 -0700  56) >>>>>>> origin/mybranch
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a reverse blame. That is like a normal blame but you provide two revisions.... one where the line was *present* and another where the line is *gone*. You will get a blame but the only thing is that the revision for a deleted line will be the last revision where the line was *still present*.... so you will want to look at the revision that comes after it.

I tackle this problem in a small project called difflame:

https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame